# d3Service in angular / ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, ionic-framework

I am trying to use d3 in angular using a factory but I keep on getting error

> Error: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'd3Service.d3().then')

Obviously I must be doing something wrong, but I just can't spot it and this has last for several days now!
Maybe you have a hint ?
thanks in advance

**d3.js**

```
angular.module('d3', [])
    .factory('d3Service', [function(){
        return {
            d3: function(){
                return !function(){ d3 code here }();
            }
        }
]);
```

**directives.js**

```
angular.module('starter.directives', ['d3'])
    .directive('d3circle', ['d3Service', function(d3Service) {
        return {
            scope: {},
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                d3Service.d3().then(function(d3){

                });
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: see http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html

Comment: see in d3.js file you wrote the module name as 'd3' and in directive.js file you wrote the module name as 'starter.services', please check the names properly

Comment: @jarandaf I followed the instructions on ng-newsletter but I just can't figure out what code to insert at   `angular.module('d3', [])
     .factory('d3Service', [function(){
       var d3;
    // insert d3 code here
    return d3;
  }];`

is it the whole code `!function(){}();` or only what is inside the brackets ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're trying to use .then on a function while .then is meant for promisses.

**Correct way to use .then()**

*Service*

```
.factory('Examples', function($http){   
getExampleData: function () {
           return $http.get('http://xxxxxx.com/api/Examples/GetExampleData')
      }
})
```

*Directive*

```
.directive('d3circle', ['Examples', function(Examples) {
        return {
            scope: {},
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                Examples.getExamplesData().then(function(data){
                // do something with data
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

To solve your problem I think you have to use $q in your service to resolve the code you want to return.

Like this example (from angularjs API)

```
function asyncGreet(name) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  setTimeout(function() {
    deferred.notify('About to greet ' + name + '.');

    if (okToGreet(name)) {
      deferred.resolve('Hello, ' + name + '!');
    } else {
      deferred.reject('Greeting ' + name + ' is not allowed.');
    }
  }, 1000);

  return deferred.promise;
}

var promise = asyncGreet('Robin Hood');
promise.then(function(greeting) {
  alert('Success: ' + greeting);
}, function(reason) {
  alert('Failed: ' + reason);
}, function(update) {
  alert('Got notification: ' + update);
});
```